# How do I allocate licence time as a limited resource in MS project?

Tags: ms-project, resources

I have a problem with allocation of licenses. The work to be done requires a software license that must be shared between my project and several others. This means that I only have that resource for a few hours a day. If I assign the license resource type as work it shows up in the project labor hours even though its not labor. That causes a problem for me to track the project cost in labor hours (there is no material cost). The only other choices for resource type are material or cost. Neither of those allow me to specify a max constraint. I suppose that I can list this resource as labor with 0 cost per hour and then do my cost tracking in dollars instead but that is not the way I report it so I'll need to translate back to hours. Is there another way?

Comment: How are you dividing the software up - by time?  If you can specify that you only have availability for use from 10:00 am to 12:00 pm, you could assign a task calendar to any task using that resource and specify "scheduling ignores resource calendars".  You can then use a material resource and because of the task calendar, the license will only be used for the two hours per day.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to keep track availability of cost type asset (License).

My suggestion is to create a resource type with cost $ 0,00 (which will do not generate any cost to your actuals) and an associate calendar to it (to set the max constraint). Finally you will have to filter out the labour hours for that resource in your report.

Comment: Anytime! Consider accepting my answer if you think it solved your issue.